# Executing MySQL query from command line

Tags: mysql, cmd

For some reason when I execute:

```
mysql -h localhost -u user -p -e "UPDATE \`dbname\`.\`core_config_data\` SET \`value\`='url' WHERE \`core_config_data\`.\`value\` LIKE 'http://%'"
```

I get

> ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'core_config_data.alue'
>   in 'where clause'

This tells me something happened with `v` but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I'd suggest removing the backticks from your query.  They aren't necessary, and could plausibly be the cause of your problem.

Comment: @fancyPants - See that `v` is missing in the error message.

Comment: @fancyPants - OP clearly stated this

Comment: Is it really necessary to `escape` back-ticks with slashes in command line?

Comment: @PM77-1 I see, thanks, sorry for not reading question properly

Comment: Jules' reply is the right answer!  Thanks!  Feel free to post it as the answer